# Python is randomly multiplying the values of an imported nested list

Tags: python, django

I am creating a web app with Django. I use a file called simulateur_data.py which contains a Class called SimulateurData which stores all the key parameters I need to use in scripts and templates. The goal is that it will be easier to change the parameters when relevant.

I use python 3.7.2 and django 2.1.7

It works fine when I import all parameters from SimulateurData, except one, which is a nested list. When I import it from another script, sometimes it import the right values, sometimes I get the nested list with a multiplicator of 137.74632546929436 applied to some values.

I first thought it was because the nested list contains a mix of integer and float, but then I converted all the values to float and still get the same problem.

Here is my app structure (I display only files and folders I think are relevant):

```
- app/
    - data/
        - simulateur_data.py
    - scripts/
        - calculs.py
```

In simulateur_data.py, here is the code of the nested list that I have problem with (table_bareme_ir is the one I import: it converts t_i_r into float):

```py
class SimulateurData(models.Model):

    t_i_r = [
        [0, 9964, 0, 0],
        [9964, 27519, 0.14, 2457.7],
        [27519, 73779, 0.3, 13878],
        [73779, 156244, 0.41, 33810.65],
        [156244, 1e+100, 0.45, 0],
    ]

    table_bareme_ir = [[float(x) for x in row] for row in t_i_r]
```

ps: I first used float('inf') then tried np.inf, and finally tested with 1e+100 thinking it was the origin of the problem. I still have the problem with 1e+100.

Here is how I import table_bareme_ir in calculs.py:

```py
from ..data.simulateur_data import SimulateurData

table_bareme_ir = SimulateurData.table_bareme_ir
```

as I said, the import sometines goes right, sometimes goes wrong. When it goes wrong, I have the following result for table_bareme_ir:

```py
table_bareme_ir = [
    [0.0, 1372504.386976049, 0.0, 0.0],
    [1372504.386976049, 3790641.1305895117, 0.14, 338539.14410588477],
    [3790641.1305895117, 10162786.146799067, 0.3, 1911643.5048628675],
    [10162786.146799067, 21522036.876624424, 0.41, 4657292.799228396],
    [21522036.876624424, 1.3774632546929432e+102, 0.45, 0.0]
]
```

it appears that some values are kept the same (third item of each nested list, which was a float smaller than 1), and some are multiplied by exactly 137.74632546929436

I already spend several hours looking at this issue but I am really despaired and do not find any logic in this behavior.

In addition, SimulateurData class contains other nested lists based on the same structure which never present any problem when imported. For example this one:

```py
    toto = [
        [0, 6500, 0.03945],
        [6500, 17000, 0.01627, 256.425],
        [17000, 60000, 0.01085, 427.26],
        [60000, 0.00814, 893.81],
    ]
```

Does someone have already faced similar issue? How can I solve this? I really want to keep all my parameters in the same place (SimulateurData) for maintenance purpose.

Comment: Modules are only imported and executed once, regardless of how many times you use the `import` statement. So if this is happening "sometimes" it probably means that you have code somewhere that is changing that value. Look at every time you reference `table_bareme_ir` and I bet you will see that you are altering it somewhere. And note that you're using lists, which are mutable. Change those to tuples and it will be impossible to change them (though `table_bareme_ir` can always be reassigned).

Comment: thank you. By investigating further it looks like that I use an inflation function on each row of the table for items 0, 1 and 3. It then modifies the class each time (I forgot classes are not immutable objects). I am trying to find a way to copy the variables from the class and manipulating them without modifying the original values in the class. Do you know how I could do that (still new to python)

Comment: You can use [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) to copy the list, and then operate on that copy..